# Java JList refresh only after minimized or maximized

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a `JList` connected to a collection.
When collection change, I need the `JList` to be automatically refreshed. But I can see that my `JList` will refresh only after I minimized (or maximized) the `JFrame`.

Why?

I'm new with Java and I'm trying to learn.

I have this collection for the list model:

```
public class UserCollection extends Vector<User> implements ListModel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2668410577023194442L;

@Override
public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener arg0) {
    System.out.println("add list! --- " +arg0.toString());
}

@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return this.get(index).getName();
}

@Override
public int getSize() {
    return(this.elementCount);
}

@Override
public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener arg0) {}

}
```

In another class, I populate the collection with `userList.add(u1);` or `userList.remove(u1);`

In the `JFrame` class I have:

```
JList list = new JList();
list.setModel(xmppManager.userList);
```

I can see on console the collection changing, and if I minimize the `JFrame` and/or maximize, the `JList` is refreshed properly...

Comment: What do you mean by "connected to a collection"?  The key is how do you maintain and change the JList's model?  If you change the appropriate model, the JList should change automatically.  You may want to show code.

Comment: i updated with code... thank you and sorry, i'm new in java and i'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Once your collection has changed, call a refresh on your JList:

```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      jlist.revalidate(); // triggers a repaint of all the items in the JList.
      jlistContainer.repaint(); // Not sure if this one is needed
    }
  });
```

How your JList model is updated?

[EDIT] Now that we have your code, you should look at AbstractListModel and implements your model in the same way, or better, extends AbstractListModel.

Actually, you add data to your collection but the model is not notified of this change!

Comment: There should be no need to "refresh" a JList if the model is updated correctly.

Comment: It depends on the item displayed in the JList. For example, you can add custom JPanels to your JList with a custom ListCellRenderer. In that case, your JPanels will not be repainted automatically.

Comment: I agree with Hovercraft.. If the model is update properly and the model fires the appropriate events and the code is executed on the EDT the list will repaint itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, I suggest you use a DefaultListModel as your JList's model.  This model will automate the change of the view (the JList) as the model changes and will make your life much easier.  If you absolutely must use a collection of your own making, then see if you can have the class that holds it extend an AbstractListModel.  If you do this, be sure to call the appropriate fireXXXX() method whenever you change data in the model.

Comment: Hi, i'm using collection because next step i sto return a custom html formatted text in getElementAt like, for example: public Object getElementAt(int index) {
  return "<html><img src="+this.get(index).getName();+">"+this.get(index).getName();
 
 }

Comment: i'm trying AbstractListModel but i have "AbstractListModel can't be resolved to a type"

Comment: Please post your code information in an edit to your original post since code doesn't show well as a comment. Also please explain what you mean by your statements above.  If you want to display an image in a JList, then you would use a custom ListCellRenderer (check out the tutorial for more on this),  and still could use a DefaultListModel object to hold the data.

Comment: Regarding AbstractListModel, if you have errors, again edit your original post, show your new code attempt and the actual error message.

Comment: ok thank you very much. i'l try ListCellRenderer. sorry but i'm new and can't vote you due to my poor reputation.

Comment: Don't worry about voting, it's not really that important -- let's concentrate on solving your problem.  Please keep updating your main post and adding comments to let us know how things are progressing.

Answer (score 0):

When you added or removed items using the add and remove methods, you were calling methods in Vector.  This updated your model but the actual JList had no way to know that the model was updated and that it needed to refresh itself.

(I think others have adequately explained how to fix the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have resolved this thanks to your help!

This is what I did:

1) In the class doing the work I have

```
public DefaultListModel userList;
```

and I populate it with `userList.addElement(user)` and `userList.removeElement(user)`

2) in the `JFrame` class, I have:

```
JList list = new JList();
list.setCellRenderer(new UsersRenderer());
list.setModel(xmppManager.userList);
```

3) and this is my `UsersRenderer`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UsersRenderer extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9210143012283239644L;
    public UsersRenderer() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        User person = (User) value;
        labelUser.setText(person.getName() + " " + person.getAddress());
        if (isSelected) {
              setBackground(Color.red);
              setForeground(Color.white);
            } else {
              setBackground(Color.white);
              setForeground(Color.black);
            }
        return this;
    }                     
    private void initComponents() {
        labelUser = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        labelUser.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        labelUser.setText("testo");
        add(labelUser);
    }
    private javax.swing.JLabel labelUser;  
}
```